# is it possible to debug node repl

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-debugger, node-repl

Is is it possible debug NODE REPL. node cmd bring the repl prompt >. within the prompt is it possible to start the debugger. say for eg

```
> hello = function(){
....debugger;
....console.log('hello');
}
>hello() --> should run in the debugger..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

### New way: node 8 >=

`node --debug` is marked for deprecation.

> [DEP0062] DeprecationWarning: `node --debug` and `node --debug-brk` are invalid. Please use `node --inspect` or `node --inspect-brk` instead.

`node --inspect` is the way moving forward.

### Old way

Start the repl with `node --debug`. Then you can can use `node-inspector` (an npm package) from  a separate terminal, and debug in your browser with the chrome developer tools by opening `http://localhost:8080/debug?port=5858` in chrome. You can, for example, set a breakpoint in the `repl.js` file in the `complete` function, and if you go to the node repl and hit `TAB`, it will trigger the breakpoint and you can debug it.

If you want the coffee-script repl, it's `coffee --nodejs --debug`.

Comment: Can I do this same this same with coffee.. coffee repl and node-inspector or what is the alternative

Comment: Yes, see updated answer. node-inspector part is the same, just the command you use to start the repl is different.